# How to search SQL records by date of birth?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL-table where I have records of my clients such as first name, last name, date of birth etc.
Now I try to find all clients by date of birth (for cron, sending holiday and birthday greetings).
Therefore, I need to find all existing clients with a specific date of birth.

For example:

In the SQL table I have a few records with these birth dates.

```
+==================+
| Date_of_birthday |
====================
|    1981-06-30    |
--------------------
|    1972-06-30    |
--------------------
|    1966-10-07    |
====================
```

Now I need to return all clients who were born on June 30th.

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE DATE(Date_of_birthday) = '####-06-30';
```

But my pattern does not seem to work properly, it doesn't return any lines.

> The hashtag character '#' should represent any numeric character, but it doesn't work.

Where is my mistake? Or do I have to write the SQL query differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(Date_of_birthday,'%m-%d') = '06-30';
```

Answer (score 2):

This query should do:

```
select *
from YourTable
where datepart(day, date_birth) = 30
and datepart(month, date_birth) = 06
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Problem solved. @ Bruno Bukavu Thai

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE right(Date_of_birthday, 5) = '06-30'
```